# Why can't Spark Streaming application receive messages from echo piped to nc command?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, netcat

I summit SparkStream use:

```
val stream = ssc.socketTextStream("192.168.206.184", 8888)
```

and create Socket server use NC:

```
[root@master ~]# nc -lk 192.168.206.184 8888
```

if I input some message into the NC terminal by hand, the saprkstream can receive message.

but,if i use NC command send message by another terminal use the following code ,the NC server terminal can receive message,but spark stream can't receive message

```
echo "message content"|nc 192.168.206.184 8888
```

Comment: hint: What's the meaning of `-lk` options of `nc`?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Add `-lk` options to the case with `echo`.

My limited experience with `nc` tells me that the issue is with the missing `-lk` options.

Quoting [the man page of nc](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nc1.html):

> **-k**      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its cur-
>                rent connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option
>                without the -l option.
>
> **-l**      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection
>                rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an
>                error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z
>                options.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w option
>                are ignored.

Luckily, the very similar Spark Streaming application is included in Spark's examples and so it is easy to reproduce.

```
// start sc.socketTextStream in one terminal
$ ./bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount 127.0.0.1 9999
```

When I execute `nc` with `echo` and without `-lk` options I get nothing in the terminal of `NetworkWordCount` example while the input gets parsed otherwise.

```
// terminal 2
$ echo "message content"|nc -lk 127.0.0.1 9999

// terminal 1
$ ./bin/run-example streaming.NetworkWordCount 127.0.0.1 9999
...
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1496230563000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(content,1)
(message,1)
```